# How can I find the path of Woocommerce "order-pay" page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm new to woo-commerce, how can I find the path for /checkout/order-pay/ from woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

It can be found in the WooCommerce settings page.

1. Login to the Wordpress admin area
2. Navigate to 'WooCommerce -> Settings'
3. Click on the 'Advanced' tab
4. Scroll down to  'Checkout endpoints' and find 'Pay'